# Find $\underset{\{x,y\}\to \{0,0\}}{\text{lim}}\exp \left(-\frac{\left| x-y\right| }{(x-y)^2}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\underset{\{x,y\}\to \{0,0\}}{\text{lim}}\exp \left(-\frac{\left| x-y\right| }{(x-y)^2}\right)$ and prove the limit exists by $\epsilon - \delta$ definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is $0$. Let $0<\epsilon <1$ and  $\delta=\frac 1 {2\ln (\frac 1 {\epsilon})}$. Note that $\frac {|x-y|} {(x-y)^{2}} =\frac 1 {|x-y|}$. Can you now show that $e^{-\frac {|x-y|} {(x-y)^{2}}}<\epsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$? [Use the fact that $\|(x,y)\|<\delta$ implies $|x-y| <|x|+|y| <2\delta$].

Comment: Don't we need to make $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ for the two dimensional case?

Comment: @helios321 Right, I have made a correction.

Comment: $|x-y| =\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy}$ ; and $x^2+y^2\ge 2|yx| $ (AM-GM); then $|x-y| \le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)} =√2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, helps?

Comment: @PeterSzilas I had typed $\|x-y\| <\delta$ instead of  $\|(x,y)\| <\delta$. You don't require any of the inequalities you have stated. It is very elementary.

Comment: KaviRamaMurthy.Fine.Thanks for update.